Scope of "set-current-directory"
In Netlogo, I have a problem using set-current-directory.
(I am running Netlogo 6.2.1 in Windows 7 with Bootcamp on a MacBookAir from 2012)
In Setup I have:
set-current-directory "C:\\Users\\LALC\\Desktop\\1 RESEARCH\\BLABLA\\BLABLABLA\\MODEL"
set-country-names-list

The function set-country-names-list is:
to set-country-names-list
  file-open "countries12.csv"
  while [not file-at-end?]
  [set country-names-list csv:from-row file-read-line]
  file-close

I get this error:
The file C:\Users\LALC\Desktop\1 RESEARCH\BLABLA\BLABLABLA\MODEL\countries12.csv cannot be found
error while observer running FILE-AT-END?
  called by procedure SET-COUNTRY-NAMES-LIST
  called by procedure SETUP
  called by Button 'SETUP'

I am not sure why it does not give me the error when it opens the file, but only when it checks file-at-end? Where is the logic?
Also, the file is precisely in that directory, how can it not find it?
Now, the Netlogo Help page
at https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/set-current-directory.html says:

The change is temporary and is not saved with the model.

What does this mean exactly? Reading this, I think it means that it is not saved when I exit the model; but within the same model execution I expect it to hold to the directory I set, until either 1) I change it to another directory later in the code, or 2) the system changes it back to the default directory when I run the model again from scratch. Is this correct?
( If this is not correct, why not fix this and make it straightforward? The directory should stay to the one I set in the code until I change it somewhere else in the code for ALL primitives referring to that file (not just file-delete, file-exists?, and file-open) or until I close and reopen the Netlogo file. In my case, I have to analyze in R the Netlogo output. To circumvent this issue, I have to put both the R and the Netlogo files in the same directory and it makes a mess. It's not the end of the world, but I am sure there are cases when this is much more important. )
Am I missing something in the use of set-current-directory?
Any suggestions?


Q4 : "Any suggestions?"

A low hanging fruit to have the intended list loaded, this shall suffice :
set country-names-list
    csv:from-file
   "C:\\Users\\LALC\\Desktop\\1 RESEARCH\\BLABLA\\BLABLABLA\\MODEL\\countries12.csv"

(A)As documented, this one-liner circumvents (we will return to this later) the scope- and other factor(s)-related doubts and issues with set-current-directory as the csv:-extension assumes the use of an absolute path to a file to be read from.(B)As documented, this also performs a built-in <iterator> behaviour, thus the intended list gets indeed loaded top to bottom, not just remain assigned by the ALAP parsed content of the very last row of the OP named CSV-file.(C)As documented, this will also completely avoid the use of manually placed, explicit NetLogo file-open and file-close commands, which is always safer, than assuming no concurrency or other implicit-only assumptions did collide ( as you already might have learned, the standard NetLogo file-commands assume only the last NetLogo file-open command, only by a weakly and ALAP-only deferred to execute designated file-reference gets used with an explicit need to "re-open" the proper file wanted, again by file-open fname1, if more than one code-paths ( any and all other concurrent agents might ) have used another NetLogo file-open fnameX primitive, leaving a <fnameX> "hanging in the wind" in the running NetLogo code-execution ecosystem, unprotected by at least a manually maintained, ASAP-tightly placed explicit file-close.

Q3 : "(...) why it does not give me the error when it opens the file?"

As documented, the standard NetLogo primitive ( command ) file-open "..." actually does not perform, for performance reasons, due to standard NetLogo language ( as-is in 2024-Q3 ) specification, any file-I/O operation at all.
None.
This is the very reason we will never see a collision right at the file-open, as the NetLogo does not try to touch anything at this very moment. It is only after it later headbangs into any of standard NetLogo true file-I/O reporters, because only at that ALAP-deferred moment the standard NetLogo code-execution engine becomes aware, whether the actual file ( so far only weakly pre-designated by some string for some future practical file-I/O use ) ought be actually touched and tried to get open for at least a read-only mode, or for a write-mode.
This is where the errors will spring out of the box.
We may use a series of syntax-supported tricks with embedding our code-under-test into nested structures of :
 carefully [ ;; TRY:
             < a-code-to-perform >
             ;; ...
             ;; -------- ON ERROR-FREE PASS UP TO HERE:
             ;; ...
             ]
           [ ;; EXCEPT:
             print ( word "<DEBUGGING LABEL#Identifier>"
                       ;; ...
                          error-message
                     )
             ]


Q2 : "Is it correct?"

No, unfortunately it is not. The OP expressed assumptions do not hold. Once a NetLogo model-session starts, only successfully completed explicit changes take place. Restarting a <NetLogo-model> by a call to setup, does not "restore" all previously active NetLogo code-executing ecosystem parameters ( like the said current directory default ).
If it were the case the NetLogo user designed code was even explicit to call set-current-directory inside the setup code, we would not be happy either. It will not help us for cases, where we need to save an interim state of the model-evolution run and re-load it at some later time so as to continue the model-evolution state-fully, i.e. without resetting the very model-state via setup.
A moderately easy option might be to create a GUI-panel Button-object, where  a manually activated, one-stop executed, set-current-directory assignment can take place ad-hoc per incident as wished or needed - for example after a restore of a state-fully saved model into a fresh new NetLogo code-executing engine session, so as to both keep the loaded model state-fully not reset and to apply our non-default target as the current valid "current directory".

"The change is temporary and is not saved with the model."


Q1 : "What does this mean exactly?"

This phrase says, that the NetLogo code-execution engine environment set-current-directory command settings are also constrained by temporal-domain too and hold only until any of following applies:

NetLogo code-execution engine session exits
NetLogo code successfully executes other set-current-directory setting

By default, standard NetLogo models do not save "the last known valid current-directory" value as its internal state. So if one would wish to do so, we have to design our own, better and context-rich strategy for such our model state-full and environment-context-aware save/restore operations.
